# How do I compare fields in two different tables using Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, hql

I need to compare fields from 2 different tables using Hibernate queries.

Table A has a field which consists of sectionId(eg 1900).

Table B has a field which consists of userId/sectionId(eg e1230-12w11-3ewq-qg22-34qa/1900).

I need to extract sectionId from table B and compare it with sectionId in table A so that I can build a row for a new table. I also need to extract userId from table B and use it as a part of this new row too.

Does hql have the ability to compare fields partially?

Comment: Have you checked the SUBSTRING(...) function and compared the required parts of the ID by yourself (=)?

Comment: Thanks Nowicki :). Substring only allows me to extract a string using their indexes. It would be great if I can use "/" to identify that there are 2 different strings. Do you have any idea? Cheers

Comment: I've summed up what was said here as well as an answer for your second question to the separate post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this using [JPQL functions](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/string): **SUBSTRING** and **LOCATE**.

LOCATE will be able to locate the particular character in your input string and will return it's place.
Then you should be able to use SUBSTRING to return just a part of the string based on the index returned by LOCATE.